# Charts doesnt show up when I use Tailwind with codeigniter4

Tags: tailwind-css, codeigniter-4, tailwind-ui

I am trying to use Tailwind with Codeigniter4 framework. I used the **soft-ui-dashboard-tailwind-main** . When I try to load the dashboard after copying the dashboard.html to my Views folder as dashboard.php and copying the assets folder to my public directory and changing all `../assets` to `<?= base_url('public'); ?>/assets` .
The dashboard page loads but without the charts and with some errors when I check my browser Chrome's inspect:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
perfect-scrollbar.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
tooltips.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
dropdown.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
sidenav-burger.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
navbar-sticky.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
chart-2.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
chart-1.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
tooltips.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
fixed-plugin.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
perfect-scrollbar.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
tooltips.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
perfect-scrollbar.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

However when I use view source and click on the links said in the errors it loads.

Comment: I don't think you needed to change the include paths? `<?= base_url('public'); ?>/assets` would resolve to `http://www.example.com/public/assets` which I don't think you want. If that `assets` folder is directly inside `PROJECTROOT/public`, then you don't need `public` in your URI

Comment: I changed the url to ../assets after pasting the folder in PROJECTROOT. I get the page rendered but with the same 404 errors for on the web console.Also charts not showing up and jquery validations not working.

Comment: It got working when I changed `var to_build ="";` inside `soft-ui-dashboard-tailwind.js` . But I still get one `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)               index.php:1` inside my web console . Also my jquery validations not working.